# Linq vs Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, linq, stored-procedures

Which one is preferable for Enterprise CMS development:
LINQ or SP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally what I do is LINQ to Views and LINQ to Stored Procedures. It's not a question of what is preferred because LINQ solves how to manage the data once it's queried where Stored Procedures are run on the SQL side to allow for query manipulation (or for me, mostly saving) of data which takes away from having the code to do it which is slower.

I would say you would want to use both if necessary. Are you saving to Entities that require multiple tables saves as one Entity? If so, use Stored Procedures with LINQ. If you're using 1 to 1 Entity relations to your tables then just use LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Stored Procedures can be used with Linq2Sql (and Entity Framework), so it isn't a choice of one or another.

Answer (score 0):

I would cache the results from the database for a CMS as you likely to get the same data requested over and over again (cache the dataset, or use page caching, or cache the objects if using LINQ).

Then it doesn't matter if you use LINQ or an SP, but I would just use LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

For simple CRUD table(no joins !!!) operations LINQ to SQL is fine, however for anything more complex (needing joins) I always use stored procedures (you can use Linq to stored procedures if you wish)

There are numerous debates around this on this site and others. For me, you can normally split the pro Linq camp into guys who have recently come into programming and have not had the history of having to use Stored procedures, ie not been heavily involved in the database side of previous projects.

Form my experience of working on several projects using pure LINQ, stored procedures and a mixture of both these are the two reasons I would stick to Linq for basic CRUD and stored procedures for anything more complex or relying on performance.

1 - Deploymenty/Security - Anyone that has worked in the real world a knows full well that having the database logic separated into stored procedures and not incorporated into the source code and released DLL is a massive advantage. You can add a proper security/access layer around each query using roles and SQL server security, imperative for any serious enterprise level company, and you can also make changes to the SQL of any stored procedure without having to do a new release of the main application (dll). I dont care how good you claim to be we have all had to fix live issues and performance bottlenecks using stored procedures and having to do this with a new application release would have been a nightmare.

2 - Performance/Code Smells - I have seen so many applications littered with huge amount of of badly written and inefficient Linq. Developers get lazy with Linq, little hidden lazy Linq to SQL queries which cause you a nightmare trying to debug performance issues on an enterprise level system - the motto 'get it done as quick as possible' seems prevalent. I have seen more Spaghetti code since the advent of Linq than I had seen with any previous class library/pattern Microsoft have released since COM.